# Google Log Stackdriver Sink/Router

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to kick off Google Cloud Function when two tables **ga_sessions** and **events** have successfully created in BigQuery (these tables can be created anytime in the gap of 3-4 hours).

I have written the following log stackdriver sink/log router to which Pub/Sub topic is subscribed (which in turn kick off google cloud function). However, it is not working. If I use sink/router individually for **ga_sessions** and **events** it works fine but when I combine them together then it doesn't work.

So my question is how do I take two different events from log stackdriver, combined them together & pass them to pub/sub topic

```
   protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId="my_dataset"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.projectId="my-project"
    protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="firebase-measurement@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId:"events"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.writeDisposition:"WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.state:"DONE"
    NOT protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId:"events_intraday"

    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.datasetId="my_dataset"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.projectId="my-project"
    protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
    protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId:"ga_sessions"
    NOT protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.load.destinationTable.tableId:"ga_sessions_intraday"
```

Thanks in advance for your help/guidance.

Comment: Just to clarify I am looking for How to do INTERSECT two log events. So in the above code  two events are separated by space. I want to send info to pub/sub only when both tables are successfully created

Comment: Can you provide more details ? What quesries / sink configuration etc ? What did you try exactly ?

Comment: What I am looking for is 

Code A
INTERSECT
Code B

Where Code A is the first 8 lines in my original code & Code B is the next 6 lines after space

I have tried to create Sink -->> PubSub -->> kick off cloud function in following scenario

a) Whole code altogether (without any operator)
b) Code A AND Code B (with AND operator)
c) Trying inserting INTERSECT which is not accepted by StackDriver

All three scenario did not work. 

If I use just Code A or Code B then it works fine but I only want Cloud function to kick off once both events happens/complete successfully

Comment: See [Logging Query Language documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language) for explanation of the available operators.
The log router examines one log at a time to determine whether to forward it to your PubSub topic. So, I'm not sure you'll be able to condition one log's export on whether another event exists in a separate table, using the log filter.

Maybe you could use (A) OR (B) to send any logs that come from either table to your Pub/Sub topic, and then on the Cloud Functions end, do some kind of tracking whether you've seen events from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to create a metric that would actually show 1 when both conditions are met.

Try creating a new logs based metric and swithc to "[query editor](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor)". There you can create your own metric using [MQL language](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-language#strict-form).

To be able to create a single metric from two "metrics" you need to use [something like this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#fetch-tabop):

```
  { fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization ;
    fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores
  } | join | div
```

And here's some useful info on how to create an [alerting policy using MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/alerts).
The code for the [alerting policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/alerts#ql-threshold-alerts) can look like this:

```
{ fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization ;
  fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores
} 
| join | div
| condition val() >1
```

This is just an example to demonstrate that it is very likely possible to create the metric to monitor the creation of BigQuery tables but you have to test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll try this & update it here. Also, just for the interest of other people, I found another way. Google dump all activities into BigQuery table cloudaudit_googleapis_com_activity_*, one can leverage this table to investigate events etc.